# How to split a table at the point that it overflows in Slides using Google Slides API

Tags: google-workspace, google-slides-api

I'm trying to generate a Google Slides presentation using data from my database that consists of entries. I want to visualize the data in the form of tables where each row will display a single entry of data.

As there's so much entries, a single table in a slide won't be sufficient to display all of them, they will inevitably overflow. To overcome this problem, I want to split the table at the point where a row will start to make the table to overflow out of the slide. Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

I've tried to "[get](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)" the presentation using the Google Slides API to see the height of each row but it doesn't seem to be reliable (two rows that visibly has different heights is listed with the same height in the JSON response)

Right now, the temporary solution that I'm doing is to basically limit the number of entries in each slides to an arbitrary number so that it looks good. But this approach would fail if any of the contents of the cells in the table wrap and take up more space